# pyspark map function return differently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
>>> rdd.collect()
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Define two map functions which I believe should be the same

```
def map2(l):
    result=[]
    for i in l:
         result.append(((i,i),1))
         result.append((i,1))
    for j in result:
         yield j
```

Output

```
>>>rdd.mapPartitions(map2).collect()
[((1, 1), 1), (1, 1), ((2, 2), 1), (2, 1), ((3, 3), 1), (3, 1), ((4, 4), 1), (4, 1)]
```

Another function

```
def map2(l):
    result=[]
    for i in l:
            result.append(((i,i),1))
    for i in l:
            result.append((i,1))
    for j in result:
            yield j
```

output

```
>>> rdd.mapPartitions(map2).collect()
[((1, 1), 1), ((2, 2), 1), ((3, 3), 1), ((4, 4), 1)]
```

Comment: Why should they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are stateful and cannot be traversed multiple times. The first for loop you execute in the second example uses all available items and leaves an empty iterator so there is nothing to add in the second loop.

If you want to traverse multiple times convert iterator to list:

```
def map2(l):
    l = list(l)
    result=[]
    ...
```